# In Google Apps Script I cant pull data from my desired sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, null, typeerror

```
function sendEmail() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheet1= ss.getSheets()[0];



var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(13, 2).getValue();
var orderId = sheet1.getRange(2,4).getValue();

var dollar = 45

var message = sheet1.getRange(2,3).getValue();




var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array



GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,orderId, message, {'from': aliases[0]});
//MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, orderId, message);
  


}
```

the purpose of the code is to send people data from a spreadsheet.
in line 3 I try pulling data from the sheet and it returns this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheets' of null
sendEmail   @ Code.gs:3
```

Comment: `getActiveSheet()` returns Class Sheet object. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivesheet) And, the method of `getSheets()` is for Class Spreadsheet. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) So in order to use `getSheets()`, please modify `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` to `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactivespreadsheet)

Comment: By the way, is the tag of `python` related to your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var sheet1= ss.getSheets()[0];
```

Should be

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1= ss.getSheets()[0];
```

OR

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet1= ss.getActiveSheet();
```

`getActiveSpreadsheet()` selects the spreadsheet (book, document) where as `getActiveSheet` gets the individual sheet within the book.